# Primitive element

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding a primitive root of a prime number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124408/finding-a-primitive-root-of-a-prime-number)

Is there a way to determine the primitive element of $Zp$ ? (where p is a prime)
If there is no general method, then I would also like to know if this is possible for special types of primes

Thank you

Comment: I think you mean [primitive root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n). No simple method is known. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots.

Comment: I think he means [primitive element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_(finite_field)).

Comment: I meant primitive elemeny

Comment: Aren't those two the same thing?

Comment: A little confusing, but if one writes "a generator of the (multiplicative) group $\,\left(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\right)^*\,$" then, perhaps, things clear off.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124408/finding-a-primitive-root-of-a-prime-number

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Page 20 in this script](http://preterhuman.net/texts/cryptography/Number%20Theory%20An%20Related%20Alghoritm%20In%20Cryptography.pdf) will help you.