# Shortest way finding a primitive root of $15$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Note that Euler phi function $\phi(15)=8$.
Note that $\{ 2,\ 4,\ 7,\ 8,\ 11,\ 13,\ 14 \}$ is the set of relative numbers to $
15$. And $$ 2^4\equiv 1\ (15)$$ so that since $4<\phi(15)$, $2$ is not primitive. So we completed by **testing six times more**, and we concluded that there exists no primitive.

Here I have a question : Is there more shorter proof ?

Comment: The ["Finding Primitive Roots"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots) section of the Primitive Roots page of Wikipedia has a relevant discussion. Also see this earlier [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124408/finding-a-primitive-root-of-a-prime-number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest way is to quote the general theorem about which numbers have a primitive root.

But for $15$, note that $\varphi(3)=2$, and $\varphi(5)=4$. The lcm of these is $4$, so if $a$ is relatively prime to $15$, we have $a^4\equiv 1\pmod{15}$. Since $\varphi(15)=8$, there is no primitive root.

Comment: $(a^4-1)(a^4+1)\equiv 0\ (15)$ and $a^4 \equiv 1\ (5)$. So we conclude. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. For more details, you may want to look at the Carmichael function.