# Primitive root of unity with certain conditions

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

Find a primitive $k$-th root of unity $w$ modulo some prime $p$, where $k\geq a$ and $p\geq b$ where $a,b$ are chosen constants.

After looking online, I know I can find such values from tables, e.g. [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Table_of_primitive_roots). But to hand does anyone know of an algorithm or theorem or something which can produce the required $w, p, k$? (Perhaps this is a tall order and I'm not that familiar with abstract algebra so apologies if that's the case)

*Example:* Suppose $p>3$ and we require $k\geq 5$, then from the table I can see that $p=7$ so that $w\in\{3,5\}$ and $k=6$ will satisfy the conditions.

*Update:* After a bit more searching I [found this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity_modulo_n#Finding_a_primitive_k-th_root_of_unity_modulo_n) which seems to make use of the [Charmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function). Also found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124408/finding-a-primitive-root-of-a-prime-number). Looks like it's difficult without any conditions! Oh well.