# Primitive Root and Generators in Number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Q1. How to find primitive root and generators modulo $97$?

Q2. Is there anyway to find the generators modulo $97$ in an easy way?

Comment: For Q1, why not try the residue class $k = 2, \dots \frac{97 - 1}{2}$? If $k^{97 - 2} \ne 1 \bmod 97$, then $\operatorname{ord}_{\mathbb{Z}/(97 - 1)\mathbb{Z}} k = 97 - 1$, which is a primitive root / generator.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124408/finding-a-primitive-root-of-a-prime-number

Comment: @AlexVong That's not right. $2^{95}\neq 1$, but the [order of $2$ is $48$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=order+of+2+modulo+97) (in fact, any element with an even order would satisfy $k^{97-2}\neq 1$).

Comment: What is the difference between primitive roots and generators?

Comment: @Arthur You are right, we should instead find the factors of $97 - 1$, called them $a_i$, and check $k^{a_i} \ne 1$.

Comment: @lhf I think they are just different names.

Comment: hi sir i dont get it could u add a site Or book that should help me out in this i would be very thank ful

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots

Answer (score 2):

[No efficient method is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots) for finding primitive roots, though [typically there is a small one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Order_of_magnitude_of_primitive_roots).

For $97$, the smallest primitive root is $5$. You need to test $2$ and $3$ but not $4$ since $2$ fails.

Once you find a primitive root mod $p$, call it $g$, then all other ones are $g^k$ with $k$ coprime with $p-1$.

Comment: You *never* need to test 4, since it's a square.

Answer (score 0):

***HINT***

First notice that $97$ is prime.

Now prove-or take for granted if you must-that $x\neq 0$ is a primitive element modulo $97$ iff $x^{32}\equiv 1\operatorname{mod} 97$ and $x^{48} \equiv 1\operatorname{mod}97.$