# Generators/primitive roots/primitive elements of Prime fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, prime-numbers, finite-fields

Algebra by Michael Artin Exer 3.1.7 (Actually Exer 7 of Ch3.2)

> By finding primitive elements, verify that the multiplicative group $\mathbb F_p^{\times}$ is cyclic for all primes $p < 20$.

After some highly tedious manual computation (or excel/sheets, wolfram etc), we obtain that for each prime less than 20, we have, resp, the following as possible generators $1,2,3,3,7,11,11,13$. There are other generators for most of the primes less than 20, but are there patterns or properties possible generators? Like every 2p-5 is a generator of $\mathbb F_p^{\times}$ or every generator of $\mathbb F_p^{\times}$ is odd or prime if p > 5 or something.

Comment: There is, in general, no efficient way to find a generator.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks! ^-^ Post as answer?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Wait, do you disagree with P Vanchinathan? Or does your 'in general' refer to all primes $p$ instead of just primes less than 20?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2512103/589

Comment: "efficient" means "significantly better than trial and error". For $p<20$, trial and error doesn't take long.

Comment: @lhf Thanks! ^-^

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ok but what is the trial and error here? My thought was to try every number in $\mathbb F_p^{\times}$ and keep multiplying it to itself to see if I can generate the whole $\mathbb F_p^{\times}$, but [apparently, I can just do the primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2958910/140308) because if a generates $\mathbb F_p^{\times}$, then $a$ is prime? I was thinking [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2956479/140308) might be relevant, but $\mathbb F_p^{\times}$ doesn't have prime order...Is Fermat's little theorem relevant here?

Comment: No, primitive roots don't have to be primes. Probably best to have a look at the link @lhf gives, and the link you'll find there to Wikipedia.

Comment: There are results of the form that the smallest generator is less than some fractional power of $p$, possibly times a constant, possibly including a logarithmic factor

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Order_of_magnitude_of_primitive_roots). Unconditionally, the smallest primitive root is below $Cp^{\frac14+\epsilon}$ where the factor $C$ depends on $\epsilon>0$. Conditionally to GRH the smallest primitive root is $O(\log^6p)$.

Comment: I hope it is clear that those results are highly non-trivial.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Posted an answer. So Fermat's little theorem IS relevant? I was thinking to multiply both sides of equation in FLT with $a^{-1}$, which exists for $a \not\equiv 0$. Either that or Euler's theorem (at least that's my understanding based on [Wiki for Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Using_Euler's_theorem)).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I saw those just awhile ago. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My paraphrasing based on this section from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots) as pointed out as by lhf in [h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spivak_pronoun) [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2958882/generators-primitive-roots-primitive-elements-of-prime-fields#comment6109178_2958882) to h [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2512103/140308).

> For a prime $p$, if the multiplicative order of a number m modulo p is equal to $\varphi \left(p\right) = p-1$ (the order of $\mathbb F_p^{\times}$), then it is a primitive root. In fact the converse is true: If m is a primitive root modulo p, where $p$ is prime, then the multiplicative order of m is $\varphi \left(p\right)=p-1$. We can use this to test for primitive roots.

Comment: Of course, for most $n$, there is no $m$ of order $\phi(n)$. E.g., $\phi(8)=4$, but there are only elements of orders 1 and 2.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you! How is my edit please? =)

Answer (score 1):

You have said there are "other generators for most primes". If by most you mean "other the primes 2 and 3" it is ok. Actually from $p\geq5$ one is guaranteed to have more than one generator. The number is given by $\phi(p-1)$.

(The calculation for $p<20$ can not be termed tedious. As one can always omit squares from consideration and as there are just 8 primes up to 20 one can get them all without software in less than 5 minutes.)

Comment: Thanks, but what about the actual generators? (Ponders more) ah, the generators must be prime? I edited question to clarify.

Comment: Wait why can we omit squares? See. I knew there were some shortcuts or properties in doing this instead of testing out every number!

Comment: The order being $ p- 1$ is even. So the homomorphism   $x \mapsto x^2$  is not onto. So all the elements in the image subgroup consisting of squares  can generate only a proper subgroup hence can't be primitive roots.

Comment: Is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738500/) the proof of your first 2 statements? Thanks!