# Generating an element of a specific order if I know the prime factors of $N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, computational-complexity, prime-factorization

Let $N$ be an integer and suppose we know the prime factorization of $N$.
Will there then be a way of finding an element of a desired order in the multiplicative group of integers modulo $N$?

Let's say we input $k$ and we want to find an element $a$ of order $k$
in the multiplicative group of integers modulo $N$.
Will that be possible if we know the prime factorization of $N$? Currently, I am not sure how that can be done.
We can surely compute $\phi(N)$, factorize it, and raise a given element to all the factors of $\phi(N)$ to determine the order but I am not sure how we can find an element, given its order.
Any input would be helpul

Comment: For clarification: is your question equivalent to "Given integer $N$ and order $k$, can we find $a<N$ such that $a^k \pmod N \equiv 1$ ?....  If so, the answer is "Yes, but AFAIK there's no efficient method of doing so." Note that the given exponent $k \mid \phi(N)$, so you really have to perform that step to even ask the question.

Comment: @EricSnyder Yes thats my question! If I know the factorization of $N$ and also $phi(N)$ then do you know any efficiency method of doing that?

Comment: @EricSnyder If not, is there a way to find an $a$ that has order GREATER than a given value, say $T$? Is that possible?

Comment: In that last case, trial and error is quite likely to be efficient-ish. Small bases generally have higher order, though, caveat, this is a tendency and not a rule. For instance, $2$ (in modulo $p$) often has order $p-1$ or $(p-1)/2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Find an element with order more than a specified lower bound.

Answer (score 2):

If we know how to compute the primitive root modulo $n$, this problem can also be solved.
Recall that $g$ is a primitive root modulo $n$ if and only if $g$ is a generator of the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$.

So let $N=p_1^{r_1}\ldots p_s^{r_s}$ where $p_{1},p_{2},\ldots ,p_{r}$ are the distinct primes dividing $N$ and
let $k$ be an integer greater than $1$.
Let $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$ be the multiplicative group of integers modulo $N$.
We know $|\mathbb{Z}_N^*|=\phi(N)=p_1^{r_1-1}\ldots p_s^{r_s-1}(p_1-1)\ldots(p_s-1)$,
where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.
Let us also assume that $k$ divides $\phi(N)$, otherwise there is no element of order $k$
in the group $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$.

1. We can assume that $k$ is a prime power.
   Indeed, if $k=mn$, $\operatorname{gcd}(m, n) = 1$, and $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_N^*$ have orders of $m$ and $n$, respectively,
   then $|ab|=mn$.
2. Let $q$ be a prime and $k=q^t$.
   If $k$ does not divide $p_i^{r_i-1}(p_i-1)$ for every $i$, then there is no element of order $k$
   in the group $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$.
3. Let $k$ divide $p_i^{r_i-1}(p_i-1)$ and $p_i$ be a odd prime.
   Let $g$ be a primitive root modulo $p_i^{r_i}$.
   Let us take
   $$
   b=g^{p_i^{r_i-1}(p_i-1)/k}.
   $$
   It is clear that
   $$
   b^k\equiv1\pmod{p_i^{r_i}},\hbox{ and } b^l\not\equiv1\pmod{p_i^{r_i}} \hbox{ for all }1\leq l<k.
   $$
   By the Chinese remainder theorem  there exists an integer $a$ that
   $$
   a\equiv b\pmod{p_i^{r_i}} \hbox{ and } a\equiv1\pmod{p_j^{r_j}} \hbox{ if }j\neq i. 
   $$
   We have $a^k\equiv b^k\equiv1\pmod{N}$ and $a^l\not\equiv1\pmod{N}$  for each $0<l<k$.
4. Let $p_1=2$, $k=2^t$ divide $2^{r_1-1}$, and  $k$ does not divide $p_i^{r_i-1}(p_i-1)$ for every $i>1$.
   If $t=r_1-1$, then there are no solutions.
   If $t=r_1-2$, then $b=3$ has order $2^t$ in the group $\mathbb{Z}_{2^{r_1}}^*$.
   The other cases are now obvious.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But there is no deterministic and efficient way to compute the primitive root mod N right? Only randomized algorithms?

Comment: @prestonphilly
 I didn't bother to point out, but your problem is equivalent in complexity to a primitive root search problem. A small review on primitive root finding and further references can be found in DanaJ's reply https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645891/

Comment: Thanks! I looked them up and they seem to be probabilistic methods. So no deterministic method is known yet for primitive root finding?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this field, but I think it's worth seeing Victor Shoup's work https://www.shoup.net/papers/primroots.pdf