# Why is it sufficient to only check ${s/p_i}$ powers in finding primitive root?

Tags: totient-function, primitive-roots

In [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/133720) to [Finding a primitive root of a prime number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124408),
Vadim only checks $\,a^{\large s/p_i}\bmod p\,$ to check a primitive root. It works but why it is sufficient just to check only the powers ${s/p_i}$ rather than powers of all divisors of $\phi(p)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a special case of the following, which uses the fact that every *proper* factor of $\,n\,$ divides some *maximal* proper factor $\,n/p,\,$ where $p$ ranges over the prime factors of $\,n\,$ (an immediate consequence of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic = *existence* and *uniqueness* of prime factorizations).

**Order Test** $\ \,a\,$ has order $\,n\iff a^{\large n} \equiv 1\,$ but $\,a^{\large n/p} \not\equiv 1\,$ for every prime $\,p\mid n.\,$

**Proof** $\ (\Leftarrow)\ $ If $\,a\,$ has $\,\color{#c00}{{\rm order}\ k}\,$ then $\,k\mid n\,$ ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242)).  If $\:k < n\,$ then $\,k\,$ is *proper* factor of $\,n\,$ therefore  $\,k\,$ arises by deleting at least one prime $\,p\,$ from the prime factorization of $\,n,\,$ hence $\,k\mid n/p,\,$ say $\, kj = n/p,\ $ so $\ a^{\large n/p} \equiv (\color{#c00}{a^{\large k}})^{\large j}\equiv \color{#c00}1^{\large j}\equiv 1,\,$ contra hypothesis. $\ (\Rightarrow)\ $ Clear.

Comment: "therefore k  arises by deleting at least one prime p from the prime factorization of n" can you explain this elaborately? @BillDubuque

Comment: @Pias Hint: $ $ by FTA a factor of $\,n\,$ must involve the same primes in $\,n\,$ to powers no greater than those in $\,n.\,$ If the factor is *proper* then some prime must occur to strictly lower power.