# For what primes is $6$ a primitive root?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primitive-roots

While thinking about an unrelated problem, I had to decide whether $6$ was a primitive root with respect to multiple prime moduli. I could discover no obvious pattern as to primes for which $6$ is a primitive root: $11,13,17,41,59,61,\dots$; and those for which it is not: $19,23,29,31,37,43,47,53,67,71,73,\dots$. (The primes $2,3,5,7$ are not included in the analysis for the essentially trivial reason that $6\equiv 0,\pm 1$ with respect to those moduli.) After a little deeper look, I observed that $6$ is not a primitive root of prime $p\ge 11$ when $\exists n<p-1$ such that $2^n$ and $3^n$ are multiplicative inverses of each other $\bmod p$. When this occurred, it often, but not exclusively, occurred at $n=\frac{p-1}{2}$. For modest size primes, calculation is not an insurmountable obstacle, but as the primes grow in magnitude, calculation becomes correspondingly more tedious.

**My question is this:** Is there an easy way determine (short of actual calculation) for a given prime $p$ whether $6$ will be a primitive root?

Comment: Well, you could test to see if $6$ is a quadratic residue. Primitive roots can't be quadratic residues.  Beyond that...nobody knows how to determine the primes for which a given non-square is a primitive root.

Comment: I understand that the general problem may still be unapproachable, but I was hoping that since the primes I am interested in have the form $6m\pm 1$, there might be some obscure knowledge out there about the question as it applies to $6$

Comment: There is no natural number which is known to be a primitive root for infinitely many primes.  I think you can do this if you assume GRH, but I doubt that comes with a useful construction.  Maybe some density results.

Comment: See also http://oeis.org/A167794

Comment: I think, you can do no better than to determine the order modulo $6$. If a number $N$ is given from which we do not know whether it is prime, we have to check the primality anyway.  And the work is still not done. If we cannot factor $N-1$ , we might be unable to determine the order.

Comment: @KeithBackman You said you're interested in the primes that have the form $6m\pm 1$, but with the exception of $2$ and $3$, all primes have that form.

Comment: @jjagmath I was aiming for the commonality of the $6$ in the form of the primes and the $6$ for which I wish to know whether it is a primitive root. Think of it as if I were asking whether $a$ could be determined to  be a primitive root with respect to primes of the form $am\pm 1$, and then focusing on $a=6$.

Comment: Your observation about $2^n$ and $3^n$ is nearly trivial. They multiply to $6^n$ and the order of a base is the LCM of the order of each of it's prime factors at greatest.

Comment: Course we can note that $6^{-1}\equiv 5m+1\pmod {6m+1}$ and $6^{-1}\equiv m\pmod {6m-1}$  and use properties of inverses to infer things.

Comment: Additive inverse only have same order when $-1$ shows up in an even position, multiplicative inverses only have same order If I recall correctly.

Comment: $6^{3m-1}\equiv m\pmod{6m+1}$ and $6^{6m-3}\equiv m \pmod{6m-1}$ interesting.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee $6^{3m-1} \not\equiv m \pmod {6m+1}$ for $m=3$

Comment: Okay maybe I screwed up I was using the facts that $m$ is either the multiplicative inverse or it's negation for $6$ so ascribing discrete logs ... But your observation is equivalent to $19$ not working ...

Comment: It depends on what you mean by calculation. I consider any kind of a test a calculation so my answer would be no. One way to determine it is to try for all $d|(p-1)$ whether $6^d=1\ (mod\ p)$, and $6$ is a primitive root $mod\ p$ if-and-only-if $d=p-1$ is the only value of $d$ that satisfies this condition.

Comment: @Steven that's the definition.

Comment: I believe the definition of a primitive root $mod\ p$ where $p\in\mathbb{P}$ is the powers of a primitive root generate all of the elements of the multiplicative group $1..p-1$. I'm not sure if there's a more efficient test. The question here is related to the recent and more general question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124408/finding-a-primitive-root-of-a-prime-number.