# How can I find all primitive roots of 41?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

I know how to do it with smaller numbers by testing,but here we have φ(φ(41))=16 solutions out of 40 possibilities.I think I somehow have to use indices.
Actually how do I even find 1 primitive root?Should I just pick a random number and test?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Start systematically with $2,3,\ldots$. Then you'll see that there are $16$ primitive roots modulo $41$ which are 
$$6,7,11,12,13,15,17,19,22,24,26,28,29,30,34,35$$ A more general way (there is no good way in general) can be found in [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124408/finding-a-primitive-root-of-a-prime-number): "There is no general formula to find a primitive root. Typically, what you do is you pick a number and test. Once you find one primitive root, you find all the others."